# Сегментированная конструкция или двусоставное предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

На одном из интернет-ресурсов в качестве заголовков статей использованы следующие конструкции:

> "Другой" - ирландский триллер, в котором не всё так однозначно.
>   "Омен. Перерождение" - мистический триллер о зловещей реинкарнации.
>   "Инуясики" - японский супергеройский экшн.
>   "Айка" - авторская драма о маленьком человеке в большом городе.
>   "Наркокурьер" - достойное кино!
>   "Глубокие реки" - авторское кино о семье, людях и мечте.
>   "Коллекторы" - неплохой боевик, чтобы скрасить скучный вечер.

Можно ли считать, что эти случаи -  не двусоставные предложения, где первая часть - подлежащее, а вторая - сказуемое, а это сегментированные конструкции (наподобие, *Карлсберг – пожалуй, лучшее пиво в мире!*)?
Там же у того же автора используются такие заголовки:

> "Американские Боги" - премьера второго сезона!
>   "Громкая связь" - идеальные незнакомцы по-русски.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Синтаксис заголовка важен для его актуализации, а сегментация — это один из способов оформления заголовков. **Сегментация — деление высказывания на части,** в одной из которых что-либо называется, в другой сообщается о том, что уже названо.

2) В приведенных примерах в первой части дается **название фильма,** а во второй  приводится его **характеристика**: определяется жанр, дается оценка, приводятся высказывания на тему.  Вторая часть представлена в виде  **распространенного словосочетания** в И.п., но может иметь и другую форму.

3) Внешне такие конструкции  **сходны с двусоставным предложением** вида "подлежащее — составное именное сказуемое", например: "Наркокурьер" — достойное кино!  Точно такое же предложение будет являться двусоставным в тексте, посвященном этому фильму. Но здесь у него другая коммуникативная функция — сообщить  о фильме краткую информацию.

Отметим, что предложения будут иметь **разную интонацию**: в заголовке голос после первой части понижается и делается более длительная пауза.